# Adding a gradient to UIScrollView

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview

I'm trying to add a gradient in order to fade in and out text for my UIScrollView.  I got the suggestion to add a CAGradientLayer. I thought I would do something like this for start, and just cover the whole thing versus worry about the top and bottom portions since I'm new to gradients and drawing in general.  I tried this, but I don't think it's correct since my UILabel text in my UIScrollView looks unchanged.  Am I on the right track?  Thanks.

Edit:

```
    CAGradientLayer *gradient = [CAGradientLayer layer];
    CGColorRef darkColor = [[UIColor colorWithRed:0.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:0.6] CGColor];
//    CGColorRef darkColor = [[self.scrollView.backgroundColor colorWithAlphaComponent:0.5] CGColor];
//    CGColorRef lightColor = [[UIColor colorWithRed:0.8 green:0.8 blue:0.8 alpha:0.6] CGColor];
    CGColorRef lightColor = [[self.scrollView.backgroundColor colorWithAlphaComponent:1.0] CGColor];
    CGRect gradientFrame = self.scrollView.bounds;
    gradientFrame.size.height = 50;
    gradient.frame = gradientFrame;
    gradient.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: (id)darkColor, (id)lightColor, nil];
    [self.scrollView.layer addSublayer:gradient];
```

I've tried this a few different ways using different RGB, alpha values, and I can't get it look right just to have the text fade out.  I tried the backgroundColor with alpha from 0.0 to 1.0 and I do not see any changes.

Comment: Try first just to change `scrollView.backgroundColor` to check this is not a transparency `.alpha` issue of components added over.

Comment: I changed the backgroundColor to a different color and I do see the gradient.  However it's just a gradient applied over my whole scrollView area.  So it just looks like a square, versus having the text fade out.  So I'm assuming I need to use the backgroundColor, but not sure how.  Any thoughts? Thanks.

Comment: please post more code with `alpha` property involved, it is hard to *imagine* what you are doing w/o :)

Comment: The code I added is in my viewDidLoad method.  I am trying to see the effect first, before adding it to the delegate methods just so I can see if it looks correct.  I tried different alphas, from 0.0 to 1.0 for the backgroundColor to see if it made a difference, and I did not see any when I ran it in the simulator.  Only if I change lightColor, using the RGBA values like when I create the darkColor do I see anything in the simulator.

Comment: Then, if I understand well, I guess you have your problem `colorWithAlphaComponent` / solution, not using `colorWithAlphaComponent`... `UIColor` is a bit strange and has underlying classes that has different behaviors... Maybe you should directly use `CGColor`... like `CGColorCreateCopyWithAlpha`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you add the gradient to the scrollview it will scroll away with the scrollview. Adding it to the scrollviews superview should do the trick.

It still should be visible initially if it is big enough.

This works for me:

```
+ (CAGradientLayer *)maskWithHorizontalFadingBordersWithinBounds:(CGRect)bounds
{
    CAGradientLayer * maskLayer = [CAGradientLayer layer];

    id outerColor = (id)[UIColor colorWithWhite:1.0 alpha:0.0].CGColor;
    id innerColor = (id)[UIColor colorWithWhite:1.0 alpha:1.0].CGColor;

    maskLayer.colors    = @[outerColor, innerColor, innerColor, outerColor];
    maskLayer.locations = @[@0.0      , @0.025    , @0.975    , @1.0];
    maskLayer.bounds = bounds;
    maskLayer.anchorPoint = CGPointZero;

    return maskLayer;
}
```

Call this method within the appropiate initializer, be careful not to create the layer more often than necessary.

```
scrollViewsSuperView.layer.mask = [CAGradientLayer maskWithHorizontalFadingBordersWithinBounds:scrollView.bounds];
```

**Disadvantage**: The Scrollbars will be affected too, I still prefer this simple solution.

**Alternative**: Add the mask **as a sublayer** to the scroll view itself and reset its position to 0 in scrollViewDidScroll.

Comment: I prefer to embed the `UIScrollView` in a backing `UIView`, and apply the mask to the backing UIView.  But, your solution solved my problem of the trailing fade extending across the entire view... I didn't realize that I needed (4) colors instead of (3) `[outerColor, innerColor, **innerColor**, outerColor]`.